# How to make HttpClient to use the app pool identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to make an http call from website A to website B, using the website A's identity.

Using .Net fwk 4.x, I just have to make something like that:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }) {
   // Do something
}
```

In aspnetcore 2.2, an IHttpClientBuilder has been provided to manage http clients.

The same code is supposed to look to something like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("myOtherSite", httpClient => {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://something");
            })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            });
```

Then I just need to inject the IHttpBuilder where I need a client then call clientBuilder.buildClient("myOtherSite").

Using this, http request seems to be made without the pool user, despite the documentation..

Has someone done something like this?

Comment: what identity is being used instead?

Comment: Myothersite receive an anonymous call. It's working well with .Net 4.7, I absolutly do not see what I'm missing...

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) HttpClientHandler is no longer the default implementation as of .NET Core 2.1. Unless you set an explicit switch, it won't be used.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Unfortunatly, I'm not able to make it work using the SocketsMessageHandler. Just asked here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37665

Comment: did you try forcing it to use HttpClientHandler instead by setting the context switch?

Comment: Absolutly! I needed to do few more modifications, but I get it work using the context switch! Thanks for the tips! - I'm sad I could not use the netcore improvements... -

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your issue but this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.8) states that starting with core 2.1, the `System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler` class is used instead.

It has information on how to configure to allow continuing use of `HttpClientHandler` but you may want to switch or even try using `HttpMessageHandler` in place of the type you're using for the handler currently.